# How can I login to my Metamask wallet with 12-words seed phrase on commandline?

Tags: metamask, wallets, command-line

I partially lost the order of my words, I need to test about 1000 combinations at least. I want to do this on command line.

I generated the list of all potential combinations to a textfile with newline as a separator.

**How can I login to my wallet with the command line having all the potential seeds in a text file?**

Answer (score 1):

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

This tool will generate everything you want from a seed: Master private key and specific derivation path extended pubkeys. For Standard Metamask ETH you need to set the path to m/44'/60'/0'/0.

Then you need to check the first few addresses of each extended pubkey and see if they hold funds, this can be done with `web3.eth.getBalance('0x2910543af39aba0cd09dbb2d50200b3e800a63d2')`